# A CSS class is not fully applied to a button inside a span element

Tags: css, angularjs

The style in [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span) is partially not working.
I am trying to set a CSS component on my buttons.
There are three buttons in total and two of them already existed before I mand. The CSS class is successfully applied on those two buttons, but not for the only one I just have made.

1. here is the code. The button that is causing problem is the first span, "info-button".

```
<div class="buttons">
    ***<span class="button-navy">
        <button type="button" class="info-button">안내</button>
    </span>***
    <span class="button-navy">
        <button type="button" class="search-button" ng-disabled="!ctrl.displayed || ctrl.displayed.length == 0" ng-click="ctrl.printOut()">출력</button>
    </span>
    <span class="button-blue">
        <button type="button" class="search-button" ng-click="ctrl.reloadl()">새로고침</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

2. the classes with style is "button-navy" and "button-blue" with background colored tags. I tried to apply both types, but they are not working.
3. "info-button" and "search-button" doesn't have any styles
4. I have tried power refresh several times, but it doesn’t seem to be working.

If I have checked the priority on CSS, what should I check next?

Comment: please share a jsfiddle with the classes and html code pasted with the issue replicated for checking why its so!

Comment: What do you see when you use your browser devtools inspect facility? What styles are/aren't being applied?

Comment: The code you have given seems to work equally for the two navy backgrounds so we won't be able to tell from it what the problem is. Essential that you provide a snippet which definitely demonstrates the problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` as @MithunDeshan suggested?

Comment: @NarenMurali 
It simply turned out I wasnt fully aware of the names of class and the styles that are already set in the project. I am pretty embrassing of the problems I faced haha. 
Thank you for spending your time to try solve my problems!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first check you do you linked css file correctly. And if it's yes please try access classess with parent class.

Eg:-

```
.buttons .button-navy .info-button{
   your stylings
}
```

or you can use important ketword as follow,

```
color:red!important;
```

Comment: Yeah It turned out I should have put".search-button" instead of "".info-button"
I thought the styles were set in ".button-navy" class. but it was directly onto ".search-button" 
appreciate your comment!!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can achieve this effect using the background-clip property and the rgba color value. The key is to use an rgba color for the background of element1 with the desired color and the same alpha value as element2. This way, the color of element1 will be preserved, and only its opacity will be affected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
        .element2 {
          background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Semi-transparent red background */
          padding: 20px;
        }

        .element1 {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8); /* Semi-transparent blue background */
          padding: 10px;
          /* Use background-clip to only apply the background within the padding box */
          background-clip: padding-box;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="element2">
        <div class="element1">
          Content of element1
        </div>
        Other content of element2
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In this example, element2 has a semi-transparent red background, and element1 has a semi-transparent blue background. The background-clip: padding-box; property ensures that the background is only applied within the padding box of element1, allowing the content to have its own color while inheriting the opacity from the parent. Adjust the colors and alpha values as needed for your specific design.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!

Comment: Were you trying to answer a completely different question?

Comment: Consider sticking to the original posters markup to reduce confusion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).